# Parsing Lisp-Like String into Tokens and Literal Text

Tags: php, regex, parsing, token, preg-match-all

Using the PHP v8 preg_match_all($Matches) function's "Match" parameter, I need to match a list of literal text **and** delimited tokens.

```
$x = preg_match_all($Regex, $Template, $Matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE); // Parse the template.
```

The catch is that tokens should be able to be nested. I need to match **only the outermost token from the nest**.

Example:

```
This {is {{Par}m1}} plus {{Par{m3a{{Parm3b}}}} a}nd {{Parm4a||{{Par}m4b||{{Parm4c||{{Parm4d||Parm}}}}}}}}.
```

Should parse into this:

```
 Match 1: This {is
 Match 2: {{Par}m1}}
 Match 3:  plus
 Match 4: {{Par{m3a{{Parm3b}}}}
 Match 5:  a}nd
 Match 6: {{Parm4a||{{Par}m4b||{{Parm4c||{{Parm4d||Parm}}}}}}}}
 Match 7: .
```

Notice above that **single** curly braces **should be allowed** *in tokens or in text*.

Only double curly braces are considered token delimiters.

The regular expression that I have so far is working **only if** there are no single curly braces in the text or tokens.

My regex:

```
(?:(?!(\{\{)).)+|((\{\{)((?>[^{}]+|(?2))*)(\}\}))
```

I cannot figure out how to allow single curly braces in the text or inside tokens without breaking the list of matches.

Any help greatly appreciated!

UPDATE

I am continuing to work on this problem and came up with this:

```
\{\{(?R)*\}\}|[^{}]+
```

It uses the recursion operator but it still suffers from the same issue in that single curly braces break the parsing.

The proper delimiter is intended to be opening and closing double-curly-braces "{{" and "}}".

Comment: Regular expressions are not generally powerful enough for parsers like this. You need to use a real lexical analyzer.

Comment: Why are non-delimited values being matched in your examples? Do you need to match both? I would think only matches 2, 4, and 6 should be present, and ending with 2 `}` as that is the delimiter. For that https://regex101.com/r/rpCUz3/1 could be used, not sure if that's what you want though

Comment: I need the text between tokens because that will also be used when the string is reassembled once the tokens are expanded to their final value. The link you posted works for matching the tokens, and that's great, but I still need the interleaving text to be matched as well. 

The tokens must also be matched to their outmost nesting level because the container function/class recursively expands the nested tokens. It's a really nice system if this one bug can be worked about (specifically, allowing single curly braces within literals and within tokens).

Comment: Try https://3v4l.org/htTAR, see https://regex101.com/r/AAzAeu/1

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. So far testing appears to be working.

The regex is

```
(\{\{)(?R)*(\}\})|(?:(?!\{\{|\}\}).)+
```

Testing

Parsing this:

```
{{one}}{}This is {{Pa}rm1}} p{}lus {{P{ar{}m2}} and2 {{Close1}}{{Close2}} {{Par{m3a{{Parm3}b}}}} and {{Par{m4a||{{Parm4b||{{Parm4c||{{Parm4d||Pa}rm}}}}}}}} end {{Par{}m5}}.
```

Yields this:

```
{{one}}
{}This is 
{{Pa}rm1}}
 p{}lus 
{{P{ar{}m2}}
 and2 
{{Close1}}
{{Close2}}
 
{{Par{m3a{{Parm3}b}}}}
 and 
{{Par{m4a||{{Parm4b||{{Parm4c||{{Parm4d||Pa}rm}}}}}}}}
 end 
{{Par{}m5}}
.
```

So far seems to be working.